# uiscrollview subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

just creating a subclass of uiscrollview here and im trying to catch a -(void)scrollViewDidScrollUIScrollView *)scrollView{} in it but for some reason it is not registering.

```
@interface WallScrollView : UIScrollView{


}

@end

@implementation WallScrollView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return self;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 //some ultra fancy code     
//this code is not called for some reason
}

-(void)dealloc{

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

any ideas as to what im missing or doing wrong here? basically want to catch viewdidscroll. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to subclass the `UIScrollView`. Simply implement the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method in your delegate and set the delegate to your scrollview instance.

Comment: cheers yeah i just needed to set the delegate. completely forgot thanks